# Sed directory not found when running R with -e flag

Tags: r, sed, homebrew

When I try to run the following command:

`R --slave --no-save --no-restore -e "print('foo')"`

I get:

`/usr/local/bin/R: line 193: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
ERROR: option '-e' requires a non-empty argument`

Apparently `brew` recently moved the `ENV` folder to a new path (see [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/a02be9eea204264ce48827ac365c8b53b986d66a)). I know I can easily symlink the new sed dir to fix the issue but I wanted to know if there is a better workaround / fix (and eventually if this will be fixed in the R source code).

Comment: Did you try reinstalling R? Something seems to be messed up beyond repair.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I tried reinstalling and it did no t solve the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a reproducible problem — http://stackoverflow.com/q/38441722/1968 — it should probably be reported as a bug to Homebrew.

Comment: I submitted an issue report to Git. Please let me know if you think I should add some more information. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/553

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because `brew` has changed it's paths in [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/a02be9eea204264ce48827ac365c8b53b986d66a) so if you've run `brew update` in the last 4 days, this is what has caused the breakage.

Credit goes to [blindjesse](https://github.com/blindjesse) for this [answer](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3839#issuecomment-233742983), which is to `brew reinstall -s r`.

I ran into some other issues when I tried this though. I didn't have X11 installed and I had a conflict with the `tcl-tk` which meant that it caused some other failures when it was compiling so:

1. I installed XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org
2. Symlinked it to my homebrew folder `ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11` (note that your homebrew directory may be different)
3. `brew install homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk
   brew link --overwrite --force tcl-tk; brew unlink tcl-tk`
4. `brew reinstall -s r`

And then it worked for me. I think once the `r` bottle is upgraded this issue should disappear but for the moment this is what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded to Sierra, tried the commands above and also the directions here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/4338. After I also reinstalled the R kernel following the instructions here: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel, things started working again. Oy vey.

To reinstall the R kernel, start R in the terminal and enter the following:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()  # to register the kernel in the current R installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having `sed`'s path hardcoded, a simple workaround is to edit the R script and to change line 193 with

```
SED=$(which sed)
```