# Error using rscript

Tags: r, bash, macos, sed, rscript

I have a Homebrew version of R installed on my Mac (OS X, El Capitan 10.11.5). I've been using rscript successfully for about two weeks now. However, when I tried to run a script this morning using `rscript file.r`, I get the following error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.1/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/bin/R: line 209: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.1/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/bin/R: line 209: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
>
> Fatal error: cannot open file '': No such file or directory

(That is the full error. Yes, it appears twice, it is not a typo.)

After getting that error, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling r with homebrew. I get the same error. The only other package that I have installed since last using rscript (to the best of my knowledge) is pspp, but I see no reason why this should have affected rscript.

Of course, the error is saying that the file `/usr/local/Library/ENF/4.3/sed` cannot be found. Upon inspection of `/usr/local/library` this is, of course, true, but I don't know what the proper way to fix this is. It seems like rscript is just trying to access sed, which comes native on OS X.

Any ideas on what I can do?

This was found to be a bug contained within Homebrew/science. The error report can be found here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3839

Temporary fix for this (tested on OS X,  as of 07-19-2016 12:54 PM central) from ck37 on github:

```
mkdir /usr/local/Library/ENV
ln -s /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/ /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3
```

Comment: Do you call sed in your file.r?

Comment: are you able to access `sed` utility outside this script. i.e from your unix prompt. Looks like a problem with  `PATH` environment variable ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38440350/1968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the symlinks as a temporary fix, and until the `r` bottle is fixed. Short answer is to `brew reinstall -s r`.

I posted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471855/2491142) (with an explanation to why this occurs) on the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38440350/1968) question which solved this problem for me.