# Issue running R in batch mode

Tags: r

I've been working through *The Art of R Programming* by Norman Matloff for the past couple of days. One of the first examples in the book is the following:

```
# test.R 
# Creates a histogram of 100 normal variates and saves it to xh.pdf.
pdf("xh.pdf")
hist(rnorm(100))
dev.off()
```

The author says executing `$ R CMD BATCH test.R` would generate *xh.pdf*, but that didn't work. I googled "R batch mode" and managed to generate the PDF file using `$ R --no-save < test.R`. Anyone know why the second method works but the first doesn't?

**More Info:** I'm on OSX El Capitan. `$ R CMD BATCH test.R` produces a file, *test.Rout*, that contains the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.0/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 201:
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you give the outcome when you executed `R CMD BATCH test.R`?  Does this produce error?  Also your OS and R versions information may help people to figure out.

Comment: Have you tried `Rscript test.R' ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by following the steps laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440350/sed-directory-not-found-when-running-r-with-e-flag).

> 1. Symlinked it to my homebrew folder ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11
>      /usr/local/include/X11 (note that your homebrew directory may be
>      different)
> 2. brew install homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk
> 3. brew link --overwrite
>      --force tcl-tk; brew unlink tcl-tk brew reinstall -s r